# batch script to read a specific pattern and sort the files in the new folder

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder where I have millions of file somewhat like

> XXXXXX_156_1400093_20160507011119.psv

From this format I want a batch script which may ask me to input date in format yyymmdd seach for that date in the file name. Create a folder with the date and move all the files related to the specific date there.

I tried multiple examples and since I dont know scripting please help me.
Regards
Saurabh

I have tried the following code:

```
@ECHO on
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\sswarpal\Desktop\files"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*.psv"'
 ) DO (  
 MD %%a
 MOVE "%%a %%b" .\%%a\
)
POPD
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: But edit your question to do so, do not post code in comments, since comments do not preserve formatting.

Comment: Hi Bwyn I have tried multiple codes but no success. I am very new to coding. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a batch script which may ask me to input date in format yyymmdd seach
>   for that date in the file name. Create a folder with the date and move
>   all the files related to the specific date there.

Keep it simple. Use wildcards with `move` instead of a complicated `for` loop

```
set /p "day=Enter Date (YYYYMMDD): "
md %day% 2>nul
move "*%day%??????.psv" %day%
```

If you want to do it automatic (like your code suggests): just using random parameters won't help (token 1 `%%a` is  `XXXXXX`, but you want to create a subdir with the date (part of token 4)). Your parameters to `move` seems totally random.
Try this instead:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\sswarpal\Desktop\files"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=_" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d "*.psv"') DO (  
   set day=%%d
   set day=!day:~0,8!
   echo md !day! 2>nul
   echo MOVE "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d" .\!day!\
)
popd
```

Remove the words `echo` when the output looks like what you want.

Comment: Hi Stephan, The code works perfectly fine. I have 1 Million files and it makes like 365 folders per file. Is it possible to segregate the files in folders like 2015 then 06 then all the june files for 2015 in that folder.

Comment: sure - just adapt the `!day!` variable accordingly. for `YYYY\MM` folder structure: `set day=!day:~0,4!\!day:\4,2!`

Comment: I am very poor in programing and scripting. I  did the changes but getting error syntax is not correct.What I did was.set day=%%d
   set day=!day:~0,4!\!day:\4,2!
   MD !day! 2>nul
   MOVE "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d" .\!day!\

Comment: ups - sorry, typo. not `\4,2` but `~4,2`

Comment: You are great Stephan, Thanks a lot for your help.The code works perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Save the following code in a batch file (e.g. **myMover.bat**). When running the file from a command line window, supply the date you want as the sole parameter on the command line, as in:

```
myMover 20160508
```

Here's the code:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
if "%1"=="" goto syntax
SET sourcedir="C:\Users\sswarpal\Desktop\files"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
if not exist %1 MD %1
FOR /F %%i IN ('dir /b *_%1*.psv') DO move "%%~ni%%~xi" %1
POPD
goto :eof

:syntax
Echo.
Echo Syntax:
Echo %0 YYYYMMDD
Echo.
```